# Git > diffs filtered, show only certain changed classes/files

Tags: git, filter, grep, diff, git-log

I have 2 versions of a software (i.e. tag 4.1 and tag 4.2).

Now I want to filter out in which java classes of version 4.1 there were fixed bugs.

If I enter `git diff r4.1 r4.2 --name-only > patch.csv` I get a list of all changed classes from version 4.1 to 4.2. But this list also consists changes that were not based on a bug.

Is there a possibility that I can filter the result in order to only display classes which were changed because of a commit which contained the word "bug". In example "git log --grep=bug". Can I combine this with the "diff" command?

If this is not possible it would also be fine to me when I just look at the version 4.2 and get a list of changed classes that result from fixing a bug.

something like this `git r4.2 log --grep=bug --name-only`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git log r4.1..r4.2 --name-only --grep=bug --pretty=oneline` should give you a list of commit message headers and the files changed in them without the commit message itself. You could then redirect the output to get an easy to read list of classes:

```
$ git log r4.1..r4.2 --name-only --grep=bug --pretty=oneline | grep "\.java$" | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Why do you suggest only using the header and not the whole commit message for searching the word bug?
Can I define to look for only bug and not i.e. for debug? Now also commits with debug are shown.

Comment: Purpose of this is following:
I have analysed 4.1 with a tool and have as a result a bug probability for each java class. Now I want to check how well this works and therefore look for real bugs. No bugtracker does provide infos down to classlevel. So I started this experiment ;)
Would it be a good idea to extend the range from 4.1 to 4.20 in order to get more commits or is the danger to high that a bug commit from i.e. 4.6 describes a bug that was not in the analysed version 4.1.

Comment: what is the meaning of $ after the word java in your post? :)

Comment: `$` is the end-of-line character in `grep`'s syntax. In other words, the `grep` expression find lines ending in `.java`.

Comment: ok thanks!

is there a possibility to limit the results to exactly match the word "bug". Now also commits with "debugging" are shown ... 

i.e. something like this: --grep='bug' and not --grep=*bug*